# Routinely kicked off of wifi

Tags: xubuntu

I've been having a bit of a weird problem recently. Every ~15 min or so, I get disconnected from my home wifi network. The strangest thing is that all I have to do to fix the problem is click "connect", and I'll reconnect. I've tried multiple wireless cards, and they all have this problem. Any ideas?

Edit: I made a copy of /var/log/syslog three times - once before I was kicked off, once after I was kicked off, and once after I reconnected.

Interesting looking messages from before I was kicked off...

```
Sep 22 20:12:46 MYHOSTNAME NetworkManager[2363]: <info>  [1474600366.7201] device (wlx74da384206b6): Activation: successful, device activated.
Sep 22 20:12:46 MYHOSTNAME nm-dispatcher: req:2 'up' [wlx74da384206b6]: new request (1 scripts)
Sep 22 20:12:46 MYHOSTNAME nm-dispatcher: req:2 'up' [wlx74da384206b6]: start running ordered scripts...
Sep 22 20:12:52 MYHOSTNAME whoopsie[2322]: [20:12:52] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Sep 22 20:12:52 MYHOSTNAME whoopsie[2322]: [20:12:52] The default IPv4 route is: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/8
Sep 22 20:12:52 MYHOSTNAME whoopsie[2322]: [20:12:52] Not a paid data plan: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/8
Sep 22 20:12:52 MYHOSTNAME whoopsie[2322]: [20:12:52] Found usable connection: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/8
Sep 22 20:12:57 MYHOSTNAME whoopsie[2322]: [20:12:57] online
Sep 22 20:13:55 MYHOSTNAME dhclient[3816]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x8cf9073b)
Sep 22 20:13:58 MYHOSTNAME dhclient[3816]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7 (xid=0x8cf9073b)
Sep 22 20:14:05 MYHOSTNAME dhclient[3816]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9 (xid=0x8cf9073b)
Sep 22 20:14:14 MYHOSTNAME dhclient[3816]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13 (xid=0x8cf9073b)
Sep 22 20:14:27 MYHOSTNAME dhclient[3816]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7 (xid=0x8cf9073b)
Sep 22 20:14:34 MYHOSTNAME dhclient[3816]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13 (xid=0x8cf9073b)
Sep 22 20:14:47 MYHOSTNAME dhclient[3816]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9 (xid=0x8cf9073b)
Sep 22 20:14:56 MYHOSTNAME dhclient[3816]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 15 (xid=0x8cf9073b)
Sep 22 20:15:11 MYHOSTNAME dhclient[3816]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 16 (xid=0x8cf9073b)
Sep 22 20:15:27 MYHOSTNAME dhclient[3816]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 16 (xid=0x8cf9073b)
Sep 22 20:15:43 MYHOSTNAME dhclient[3816]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 21 (xid=0x8cf9073b)
Sep 22 20:16:04 MYHOSTNAME dhclient[3816]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11 (xid=0x8cf9073b)
Sep 22 20:16:15 MYHOSTNAME dhclient[3816]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8 (xid=0x8cf9073b)
Sep 22 20:16:23 MYHOSTNAME dhclient[3816]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 12 (xid=0x8cf9073b)
Sep 22 20:16:35 MYHOSTNAME dhclient[3816]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 19 (xid=0x8cf9073b)
Sep 22 20:16:54 MYHOSTNAME dhclient[3816]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9 (xid=0x8cf9073b)
Sep 22 20:17:01 MYHOSTNAME CRON[5943]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Sep 22 20:17:03 MYHOSTNAME dhclient[3816]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 12 (xid=0x8cf9073b)
Sep 22 20:17:15 MYHOSTNAME dhclient[3816]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 15 (xid=0x8cf9073b)
Sep 22 20:17:30 MYHOSTNAME dhclient[3816]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 15 (xid=0x8cf9073b)
Sep 22 20:17:45 MYHOSTNAME dhclient[3816]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8 (xid=0x8cf9073b)
Sep 22 20:17:53 MYHOSTNAME dhclient[3816]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 17 (xid=0x8cf9073b)
Sep 22 20:18:10 MYHOSTNAME dhclient[3816]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8 (xid=0x8cf9073b)
Sep 22 20:18:18 MYHOSTNAME dhclient[3816]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 19 (xid=0x8cf9073b)
Sep 22 20:18:37 MYHOSTNAME dhclient[3816]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 19 (xid=0x8cf9073b)
Sep 22 20:18:56 MYHOSTNAME dhclient[3816]: No DHCPOFFERS received.
Sep 22 20:18:56 MYHOSTNAME dhclient[3816]: No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
Sep 22 20:18:56 MYHOSTNAME root: /etc/dhcp/dhclient-exit-hooks.d/zzz_avahi-autoipd returned non-zero exit status 1
```

After I was kicked off, there were some new messages:

```
Sep 22 20:23:48 MYHOSTNAME dhclient[3816]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x95009651)
Sep 22 20:23:51 MYHOSTNAME dhclient[3816]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 5 (xid=0x95009651)
Sep 22 20:23:56 MYHOSTNAME dhclient[3816]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13 (xid=0x95009651)
Sep 22 20:24:09 MYHOSTNAME dhclient[3816]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 17 (xid=0x95009651)
Sep 22 20:24:26 MYHOSTNAME dhclient[3816]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10 (xid=0x95009651)
Sep 22 20:24:36 MYHOSTNAME dhclient[3816]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11 (xid=0x95009651)
Sep 22 20:24:47 MYHOSTNAME dhclient[3816]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 19 (xid=0x95009651)
Sep 22 20:25:06 MYHOSTNAME dhclient[3816]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 20 (xid=0x95009651)
Sep 22 20:25:26 MYHOSTNAME dhclient[3816]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 19 (xid=0x95009651)
Sep 22 20:25:45 MYHOSTNAME dhclient[3816]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11 (xid=0x95009651)
Sep 22 20:25:56 MYHOSTNAME dhclient[3816]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8 (xid=0x95009651)
Sep 22 20:26:04 MYHOSTNAME dhclient[3816]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 20 (xid=0x95009651)
Sep 22 20:26:24 MYHOSTNAME dhclient[3816]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10 (xid=0x95009651)
Sep 22 20:26:34 MYHOSTNAME dhclient[3816]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9 (xid=0x95009651)
Sep 22 20:26:43 MYHOSTNAME dhclient[3816]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 16 (xid=0x95009651)
Sep 22 20:26:59 MYHOSTNAME dhclient[3816]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 16 (xid=0x95009651)
Sep 22 20:27:15 MYHOSTNAME dhclient[3816]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9 (xid=0x95009651)
Sep 22 20:27:24 MYHOSTNAME dhclient[3816]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14 (xid=0x95009651)
Sep 22 20:27:38 MYHOSTNAME dhclient[3816]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 16 (xid=0x95009651)
Sep 22 20:27:54 MYHOSTNAME dhclient[3816]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 18 (xid=0x95009651)
Sep 22 20:28:12 MYHOSTNAME dhclient[3816]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 19 (xid=0x95009651)
Sep 22 20:28:31 MYHOSTNAME dhclient[3816]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11 (xid=0x95009651)
Sep 22 20:28:42 MYHOSTNAME dhclient[3816]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7 (xid=0x95009651)
Sep 22 20:28:49 MYHOSTNAME dhclient[3816]: No DHCPOFFERS received.
Sep 22 20:28:49 MYHOSTNAME dhclient[3816]: No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
Sep 22 20:28:49 MYHOSTNAME root: /etc/dhcp/dhclient-exit-hooks.d/zzz_avahi-autoipd returned non-zero exit status 1
Sep 22 20:33:58 MYHOSTNAME dhclient[3816]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0xc9331774)
Sep 22 20:34:01 MYHOSTNAME dhclient[3816]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6 (xid=0xc9331774)
Sep 22 20:34:07 MYHOSTNAME dhclient[3816]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 12 (xid=0xc9331774)
Sep 22 20:34:31 MYHOSTNAME dhclient[3816]: message repeated 2 times: [ DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 12 (xid=0xc9331774)]
Sep 22 20:34:43 MYHOSTNAME dhclient[3816]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 15 (xid=0xc9331774)
Sep 22 20:34:58 MYHOSTNAME dhclient[3816]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 20 (xid=0xc9331774)
Sep 22 20:35:18 MYHOSTNAME dhclient[3816]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 15 (xid=0xc9331774)
Sep 22 20:35:33 MYHOSTNAME dhclient[3816]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14 (xid=0xc9331774)
Sep 22 20:35:47 MYHOSTNAME dhclient[3816]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 15 (xid=0xc9331774)
```

Then, after I reconnected...

```
    Sep 22 20:36:02 MYHOSTNAME dhclient[3816]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 21 (xid=0xc9331774)
Sep 22 20:36:03 MYHOSTNAME NetworkManager[2363]: <warn>  [1474601763.0898] device (wlx74da384206b6): disconnecting connection 'Noon's Network 1' for new activation request.
Sep 22 20:36:03 MYHOSTNAME NetworkManager[2363]: <info>  [1474601763.0899] device (wlx74da384206b6): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'new-activation') [100 110 60]
Sep 22 20:36:03 MYHOSTNAME NetworkManager[2363]: <info>  [1474601763.0900] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTING
Sep 22 20:36:03 MYHOSTNAME whoopsie[2322]: [20:36:03] offline
Sep 22 20:36:03 MYHOSTNAME NetworkManager[2363]: <info>  [1474601763.1487] device (wlx74da384206b6): disconnecting for new activation request.
Sep 22 20:36:03 MYHOSTNAME NetworkManager[2363]: <info>  [1474601763.1490] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="1f1a25b1-0220-4da4-9504-d5c6aaae1872" name="Noon's Network 1" pid=3006 uid=1000 result="success"
Sep 22 20:36:03 MYHOSTNAME NetworkManager[2363]: <info>  [1474601763.1497] device (wlx74da384206b6): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'new-activation') [110 30 60]
Sep 22 20:36:03 MYHOSTNAME avahi-daemon[2366]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::a390:b89b:c84e:64e3 on wlx74da384206b6.
Sep 22 20:36:03 MYHOSTNAME avahi-daemon[2366]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlx74da384206b6.IPv6 with address fe80::a390:b89b:c84e:64e3.
Sep 22 20:36:03 MYHOSTNAME avahi-daemon[2366]: Interface wlx74da384206b6.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Sep 22 20:36:03 MYHOSTNAME NetworkManager[2363]: <info>  [1474601763.1682] dhcp4 (wlx74da384206b6): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 5630
Sep 22 20:36:03 MYHOSTNAME NetworkManager[2363]: <info>  [1474601763.1683] dhcp4 (wlx74da384206b6): state changed bound -> done
Sep 22 20:36:03 MYHOSTNAME kernel: [ 7690.093191] wlx74da384206b6: deauthenticating from 20:c9:d0:a4:3e:32 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Sep 22 20:36:03 MYHOSTNAME wpa_supplicant[2508]: wlx74da384206b6: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=20:c9:d0:a4:3e:32 reason=3 locally_generated=1
Sep 22 20:36:03 MYHOSTNAME NetworkManager[2363]: <info>  [1474601763.1840] dns-mgr: Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Sep 22 20:36:03 MYHOSTNAME avahi-daemon[2366]: Withdrawing address record for 10.0.1.11 on wlx74da384206b6.
Sep 22 20:36:03 MYHOSTNAME avahi-daemon[2366]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlx74da384206b6.IPv4 with address 10.0.1.11.
Sep 22 20:36:03 MYHOSTNAME avahi-daemon[2366]: Interface wlx74da384206b6.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Sep 22 20:36:03 MYHOSTNAME dnsmasq[2838]: setting upstream servers from DBus
Sep 22 20:36:03 MYHOSTNAME NetworkManager[2363]: <info>  [1474601763.2123] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Sep 22 20:36:03 MYHOSTNAME NetworkManager[2363]: <info>  [1474601763.2126] device (wlx74da384206b6): Activation: starting connection 'Noon's Network 1' (1f1a25b1-0220-4da4-9504-d5c6aaae1872)
Sep 22 20:36:03 MYHOSTNAME dbus[2337]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service'
Sep 22 20:36:03 MYHOSTNAME NetworkManager[2363]: <warn>  [1474601763.2136] sup-iface[0x1fd6a10,wlx74da384206b6]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
Sep 22 20:36:03 MYHOSTNAME NetworkManager[2363]: <info>  [1474601763.2138] device (wlx74da384206b6): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Sep 22 20:36:03 MYHOSTNAME NetworkManager[2363]: <info>  [1474601763.2260] device (wlx74da384206b6): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Sep 22 20:36:03 MYHOSTNAME NetworkManager[2363]: <info>  [1474601763.2261] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Sep 22 20:36:03 MYHOSTNAME NetworkManager[2363]: <info>  [1474601763.2270] device (wlx74da384206b6): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Sep 22 20:36:03 MYHOSTNAME NetworkManager[2363]: <info>  [1474601763.2273] device (wlx74da384206b6): Activation: (wifi) access point 'Noon's Network 1' has security, but secrets are required.
Sep 22 20:36:03 MYHOSTNAME NetworkManager[2363]: <info>  [1474601763.2273] device (wlx74da384206b6): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none') [50 60 0]
Sep 22 20:36:03 MYHOSTNAME NetworkManager[2363]: <info>  [1474601763.2305] device (wlx74da384206b6): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none') [60 40 0]
Sep 22 20:36:03 MYHOSTNAME NetworkManager[2363]: <info>  [1474601763.2308] device (wlx74da384206b6): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Sep 22 20:36:03 MYHOSTNAME NetworkManager[2363]: <info>  [1474601763.2309] device (wlx74da384206b6): Activation: (wifi) connection 'Noon's Network 1' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Sep 22 20:36:03 MYHOSTNAME NetworkManager[2363]: <info>  [1474601763.2310] Config: added 'ssid' value 'Noon's Network'
Sep 22 20:36:03 MYHOSTNAME NetworkManager[2363]: <info>  [1474601763.2310] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Sep 22 20:36:03 MYHOSTNAME NetworkManager[2363]: <info>  [1474601763.2310] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK'
Sep 22 20:36:03 MYHOSTNAME NetworkManager[2363]: <info>  [1474601763.2310] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
Sep 22 20:36:03 MYHOSTNAME NetworkManager[2363]: <info>  [1474601763.2310] Config: added 'psk' value '<omitted>'
Sep 22 20:36:03 MYHOSTNAME NetworkManager[2363]: <info>  [1474601763.2321] sup-iface[0x1fd6a10,wlx74da384206b6]: config: set interface ap_scan to 1
Sep 22 20:36:03 MYHOSTNAME systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Sep 22 20:36:03 MYHOSTNAME dbus[2337]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Sep 22 20:36:03 MYHOSTNAME nm-dispatcher: req:1 'down' [wlx74da384206b6]: new request (1 scripts)
Sep 22 20:36:03 MYHOSTNAME systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Sep 22 20:36:03 MYHOSTNAME nm-dispatcher: req:1 'down' [wlx74da384206b6]: start running ordered scripts...
Sep 22 20:36:03 MYHOSTNAME wpa_supplicant[2508]: wlx74da384206b6: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
Sep 22 20:36:03 MYHOSTNAME kernel: [ 7690.184859] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
Sep 22 20:36:03 MYHOSTNAME kernel: [ 7690.184863] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
Sep 22 20:36:03 MYHOSTNAME kernel: [ 7690.184864] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
Sep 22 20:36:03 MYHOSTNAME kernel: [ 7690.184867] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Sep 22 20:36:03 MYHOSTNAME kernel: [ 7690.184869] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Sep 22 20:36:03 MYHOSTNAME kernel: [ 7690.184870] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Sep 22 20:36:03 MYHOSTNAME kernel: [ 7690.184872] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Sep 22 20:36:03 MYHOSTNAME kernel: [ 7690.184874] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
Sep 22 20:36:03 MYHOSTNAME kernel: [ 7690.184876] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
Sep 22 20:36:03 MYHOSTNAME kernel: [ 7690.184878] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Sep 22 20:36:03 MYHOSTNAME kernel: [ 7690.184879] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
Sep 22 20:36:04 MYHOSTNAME wpa_supplicant[2508]: wlx74da384206b6: SME: Trying to authenticate with 20:c9:d0:a4:3e:32 (SSID='Noon's Network' freq=2462 MHz)
Sep 22 20:36:04 MYHOSTNAME kernel: [ 7690.984416] wlx74da384206b6: authenticate with 20:c9:d0:a4:3e:32
Sep 22 20:36:04 MYHOSTNAME kernel: [ 7691.007713] wlx74da384206b6: send auth to 20:c9:d0:a4:3e:32 (try 1/3)
Sep 22 20:36:04 MYHOSTNAME NetworkManager[2363]: <info>  [1474601764.0838] device (wlx74da384206b6): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> authenticating
Sep 22 20:36:04 MYHOSTNAME wpa_supplicant[2508]: wlx74da384206b6: Trying to associate with 20:c9:d0:a4:3e:32 (SSID='Noon's Network' freq=2462 MHz)
Sep 22 20:36:04 MYHOSTNAME kernel: [ 7691.010430] wlx74da384206b6: authenticated
Sep 22 20:36:04 MYHOSTNAME kernel: [ 7691.012050] wlx74da384206b6: associate with 20:c9:d0:a4:3e:32 (try 1/3)
Sep 22 20:36:04 MYHOSTNAME NetworkManager[2363]: <info>  [1474601764.0916] device (wlx74da384206b6): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Sep 22 20:36:04 MYHOSTNAME kernel: [ 7691.084296] wlx74da384206b6: RX AssocResp from 20:c9:d0:a4:3e:32 (capab=0x1431 status=0 aid=5)
Sep 22 20:36:04 MYHOSTNAME wpa_supplicant[2508]: wlx74da384206b6: Associated with 20:c9:d0:a4:3e:32
Sep 22 20:36:04 MYHOSTNAME kernel: [ 7691.185057] wlx74da384206b6: associated
Sep 22 20:36:04 MYHOSTNAME kernel: [ 7691.187145] wlx74da384206b6: Limiting TX power to 30 (30 - 0) dBm as advertised by 20:c9:d0:a4:3e:32
Sep 22 20:36:04 MYHOSTNAME NetworkManager[2363]: <info>  [1474601764.2666] device (wlx74da384206b6): supplicant interface state: associating -> 4-way handshake
Sep 22 20:36:04 MYHOSTNAME wpa_supplicant[2508]: wlx74da384206b6: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=COUNTRY_IE type=COUNTRY alpha2=US
Sep 22 20:36:04 MYHOSTNAME kernel: [ 7691.223045] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: US
Sep 22 20:36:04 MYHOSTNAME kernel: [ 7691.223049] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: FCC
Sep 22 20:36:04 MYHOSTNAME kernel: [ 7691.223050] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
Sep 22 20:36:04 MYHOSTNAME kernel: [ 7691.223052] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 3000 mBm), (N/A)
Sep 22 20:36:04 MYHOSTNAME kernel: [ 7691.223054] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 1700 mBm), (N/A)
Sep 22 20:36:04 MYHOSTNAME kernel: [ 7691.223057] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2300 mBm), (0 s)
Sep 22 20:36:04 MYHOSTNAME kernel: [ 7691.223058] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2300 mBm), (0 s)
Sep 22 20:36:04 MYHOSTNAME kernel: [ 7691.223060] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 3000 mBm), (N/A)
Sep 22 20:36:04 MYHOSTNAME kernel: [ 7691.223062] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm), (N/A)
Sep 22 20:36:05 MYHOSTNAME wpa_supplicant[2508]: wlx74da384206b6: WPA: Key negotiation completed with 20:c9:d0:a4:3e:32 [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
Sep 22 20:36:05 MYHOSTNAME wpa_supplicant[2508]: wlx74da384206b6: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 20:c9:d0:a4:3e:32 completed [id=0 id_str=]
Sep 22 20:36:05 MYHOSTNAME NetworkManager[2363]: <info>  [1474601765.1814] device (wlx74da384206b6): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
Sep 22 20:36:05 MYHOSTNAME NetworkManager[2363]: <info>  [1474601765.1814] device (wlx74da384206b6): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.  Connected to wireless network 'Noon's Network'.
Sep 22 20:36:05 MYHOSTNAME NetworkManager[2363]: <info>  [1474601765.1816] device (wlx74da384206b6): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Sep 22 20:36:05 MYHOSTNAME NetworkManager[2363]: <info>  [1474601765.1820] dhcp4 (wlx74da384206b6): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Sep 22 20:36:05 MYHOSTNAME NetworkManager[2363]: <info>  [1474601765.1842] dhcp4 (wlx74da384206b6): dhclient started with pid 7574
Sep 22 20:36:05 MYHOSTNAME dhclient[7574]: DHCPREQUEST of 10.0.1.11 on wlx74da384206b6 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x7aa9bd47)
Sep 22 20:36:06 MYHOSTNAME avahi-daemon[2366]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlx74da384206b6.IPv6 with address fe80::a390:b89b:c84e:64e3.
Sep 22 20:36:06 MYHOSTNAME avahi-daemon[2366]: New relevant interface wlx74da384206b6.IPv6 for mDNS.
Sep 22 20:36:06 MYHOSTNAME avahi-daemon[2366]: Registering new address record for fe80::a390:b89b:c84e:64e3 on wlx74da384206b6.*.
Sep 22 20:36:08 MYHOSTNAME dhclient[7574]: DHCPREQUEST of 10.0.1.11 on wlx74da384206b6 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x7aa9bd47)
Sep 22 20:36:08 MYHOSTNAME dhclient[7574]: DHCPACK of 10.0.1.11 from 10.0.1.1
Sep 22 20:36:08 MYHOSTNAME NetworkManager[2363]: <info>  [1474601768.0867]   address 10.0.1.11
Sep 22 20:36:08 MYHOSTNAME NetworkManager[2363]: <info>  [1474601768.0867]   plen 24 (255.255.255.0)
Sep 22 20:36:08 MYHOSTNAME NetworkManager[2363]: <info>  [1474601768.0867]   gateway 10.0.1.1
Sep 22 20:36:08 MYHOSTNAME NetworkManager[2363]: <info>  [1474601768.0867]   server identifier 10.0.1.1
Sep 22 20:36:08 MYHOSTNAME NetworkManager[2363]: <info>  [1474601768.0868]   lease time 86400
Sep 22 20:36:08 MYHOSTNAME NetworkManager[2363]: <info>  [1474601768.0868]   nameserver '10.0.1.1'
Sep 22 20:36:08 MYHOSTNAME NetworkManager[2363]: <info>  [1474601768.0868]   domain name 'socal.rr.com'
Sep 22 20:36:08 MYHOSTNAME NetworkManager[2363]: <info>  [1474601768.0868] dhcp4 (wlx74da384206b6): state changed unknown -> bound
Sep 22 20:36:08 MYHOSTNAME NetworkManager[2363]: <info>  [1474601768.0880] device (wlx74da384206b6): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none') [70 80 0]
Sep 22 20:36:08 MYHOSTNAME avahi-daemon[2366]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlx74da384206b6.IPv4 with address 10.0.1.11.
Sep 22 20:36:08 MYHOSTNAME avahi-daemon[2366]: New relevant interface wlx74da384206b6.IPv4 for mDNS.
Sep 22 20:36:08 MYHOSTNAME NetworkManager[2363]: <info>  [1474601768.0888] device (wlx74da384206b6): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none') [80 90 0]
Sep 22 20:36:08 MYHOSTNAME avahi-daemon[2366]: Registering new address record for 10.0.1.11 on wlx74da384206b6.IPv4.
Sep 22 20:36:08 MYHOSTNAME NetworkManager[2363]: <info>  [1474601768.0892] device (wlx74da384206b6): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none') [90 100 0]
Sep 22 20:36:08 MYHOSTNAME NetworkManager[2363]: <info>  [1474601768.0894] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Sep 22 20:36:08 MYHOSTNAME NetworkManager[2363]: <info>  [1474601768.1417] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Sep 22 20:36:08 MYHOSTNAME NetworkManager[2363]: <info>  [1474601768.1419] policy: set 'Noon's Network 1' (wlx74da384206b6) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Sep 22 20:36:08 MYHOSTNAME NetworkManager[2363]: <info>  [1474601768.1420] dns-mgr: Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Sep 22 20:36:08 MYHOSTNAME dnsmasq[2838]: setting upstream servers from DBus
Sep 22 20:36:08 MYHOSTNAME dnsmasq[2838]: using nameserver 10.0.1.1#53
Sep 22 20:36:08 MYHOSTNAME dhclient[7574]: bound to 10.0.1.11 -- renewal in 34966 seconds.
Sep 22 20:36:08 MYHOSTNAME NetworkManager[2363]: <info>  [1474601768.1597] device (wlx74da384206b6): Activation: successful, device activated.
Sep 22 20:36:08 MYHOSTNAME nm-dispatcher: req:2 'up' [wlx74da384206b6]: new request (1 scripts)
Sep 22 20:36:08 MYHOSTNAME nm-dispatcher: req:2 'up' [wlx74da384206b6]: start running ordered scripts...
Sep 22 20:36:08 MYHOSTNAME whoopsie[2322]: [20:36:08] The default IPv4 route is: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/9
Sep 22 20:36:08 MYHOSTNAME whoopsie[2322]: [20:36:08] Not a paid data plan: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/9
Sep 22 20:36:08 MYHOSTNAME whoopsie[2322]: [20:36:08] Found usable connection: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/9
Sep 22 20:36:08 MYHOSTNAME whoopsie[2322]: [20:36:08] online
```

Also, I changed all instances of the network name to "Noon's network", but this "Noon's network 1" thing isn't an artifact of my censoring - everywhere you see "Noon's network 1", the original had [real network name] 1. (Also, the real network name had an apostrophe.)

I don't know what's up with that.

Edit 2:
This is odd:
[Image of Network Connections window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUYCy.png)

Comment: Immediately after this happens look in `/var/log/syslog` for messages that might explain it. Post messages here for assistance. Chili555 might ask you to run his favorite recipe or another expert will help you.

Comment: Also make sure you have the correct wireless security settings: WPA2-AES only; not any WPA/WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP.

Comment: When I go to 'edit connections' I can't find an option only WPA2, and I'm set to WPA & WPA2 Personal.